# calculate number of triangles

Tags: geometry

Given some points on $x$-axis and some points on $y$-axis. How many right angled triangles are possible if you are allowed to

1. choose two points on $x$-axis and one points on $y$ axis?
2. choose two points on $y$-axis and one points on $x$-axis?

Is it possible to solve this problem in linear time or $n\log n$?

suppose points on x - axis are at  {-4 , 2}
points on y - axis are at  {2,-8}
 then the answer will be (1 ) when two points lie on 
y-axis ((0,2),(0,−8),(−4,0)) and no other case we can found other than this.